# Why most people won't pass the dummy node to the recursive function?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I was cooking the leetcode problem, I found that most people prefer to put the `dummyNode` in upper-level function, and they don't explicitly pass it to the functions that call them. Why?
like [leetcode 530](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-absolute-difference-in-bst/)

```js
const getMinimumDifference = function(root) {
    let ans = Infinity;
    let prev = null;
    
    function dfs(node) {
        if (!node) return ans;
        
        if (node.left) dfs(node.left);
        if (prev !== null) {
            ans = Math.min(ans, node.val - prev);
        }
        
        prev = node.val;
        
        if (node.right) dfs(node.right);
    }
    
    dfs(root);
    
    return ans;
};
```

why they won't set the `prev` as a parameter to the `dfs()` function declaration?
like`dfs(node, prev)` `dfs(node.left, prev)` `dfs(node.right, prev)`

I'm trying to figure out whether I can set the `dummyNode` as a function parameter and how to write the code.

Comment: What do you mean with *"the  `dummyNode`"*? No node is created in this process, so why should there be a "dummy" node? How does this relate to your question about a `prev` parameter?

Comment: @trincot I just considered `prev` as a `dummyNode`, In my solution I did `new TreeNode(null,null,null)`, it also has  value leftpointer rightpinter like a tree node. :)

Comment: I don't see why you would need to create a new node for this. I don't see how it would help.

Comment: @trincot hah, I'm just a fresh man in coding world and  I did some messy in my coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `prev` as argument, and take its value with a `prev` parameter variable, then `prev` will be a local variable, whose value will not be altered by recursive calls. That means that when a recursive call returns, the caller's `prev` variable will still have the same value as when that recursive call was initiated.

This is not desired. `dfs(node.left)` is supposed to update `prev`, and `dfs(node.left, prev)` would not do that -- `prev` is passed by *value*.

### Example

Let's take this BST as example:

```
         4
        / \
       1   7
        \
         3
```

The minimal difference is achieved between 3 and 4 and is equal to 1.

You can see here how the output will be different when you make `prev` a local parameter variable, as `prev` will still be 1 when the comparison with 4 is made, while the correct version will see `prev` with value 3 when that comparison is made:

```js
const getMinimumDifferenceGood = function(root) {
    let ans = Infinity;
    let prev = null;
    
    function dfs(node) {
        if (!node) return ans;        
        if (node.left) dfs(node.left);
        if (prev !== null) {
            ans = Math.min(ans, node.val - prev);
        }
        prev = node.val;
        if (node.right) dfs(node.right);
    }
    
    dfs(root);
    return ans;
}

const getMinimumDifferenceBad = function(root) {
    let ans = Infinity;
    
    function dfs(node, prev) {
        if (!node) return ans;        
        if (node.left) dfs(node.left, prev);
        if (prev !== null) {
            ans = Math.min(ans, node.val - prev);
        }
        prev = node.val;
        if (node.right) dfs(node.right, prev);
    }
    
    dfs(root, null);
    return ans;
}


let root = { 
    val: 4, 
    left: { val: 1, 
        right: { val: 3 }},
    right: { val: 7 }
};

console.log(getMinimumDifferenceGood(root)); // 1, correct
console.log(getMinimumDifferenceBad(root)); // 2, wrong
```

As discussed in comments, you can decide to *return* the updated value of `prev` back to the caller:

```js
const getMinimumDifference = function(root) {
    let ans = Infinity;
    
    function dfs(node, prev) {
        if (!node) return prev;
        if (node.left) prev = dfs(node.left, prev);
        if (prev !== null) {
            ans = Math.min(ans, node.val - prev);
        }
        prev = node.val;
        if (node.right) prev = dfs(node.right, prev);
        return prev;
    }
    
    dfs(root, null);
    return ans;
}


let root = { 
    val: 4, 
    left: { val: 1, 
        right: { val: 3 }},
    right: { val: 7 }
};

console.log(getMinimumDifference(root)); // 1, correct
```

Comment: Thank you,but what if i return the changed `prev` like `ans`?  If the binary search tree change to a linkedlist, the `prev`  can be returned, but in tree strcuture  It's seems hard to use the return value.

Comment: Sure, that is possible. There are many ways to do it. What is your question then?

Comment: I want to know how can i use the return value `prev` in BST like in linkedlist.

Comment: Just return `prev` and take it? There is nothing special about it. I don't get what the issue is. I added a snippet to my answer.

Comment: I want to know how to write the code use returned vale `prev` and `ans` ....

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Did you check the addition I made to my answer?

Comment: thanks, i got it. I missed the code you mentioned.